# How to access Interactive Generator block (IG) in Vector CANoe Simulation through Python?

Tags: automated-tests, canoe, system-testing

I am trying to automate some CANoe functions using a python tool.

I am unable to access the particulars of the CAN IG? Is there anyway I can do it so that I can control it using Python?

Comment: What have you done so far? How are you accessing CANoe from Python? Via COM?

Comment: I use a company tool which gives me access to the canoe through python. I got all the sessions and signal values and functionalities through python. However, it is this CAN IG that I am unable to access

Comment: How should we able to support you using your company tool?

Comment: I just want to know how to access the CAN IG. To open it and find its coding. How to view its CAPL coding.

Comment: First of all, there is not CAPL in an Interactive Generator. That's why it is called _interactive_. Still, we have no idea, how you use Python to access CANoe. CANoe has a COM interface, is this used?

Comment: As mentioned before, its a company tool. I do not know specifically how it access CANoe.

Is there a way to enable/disable the IG? I know pressing spacebar does it. But i want to know where this is coded

Comment: The functionality of the interactive generator is _coded_ in CANoe. Probably there is a way to disable it via the COM interface, but no idea whether your company tool supports using that interface

Comment: Would it be possible to do it via python?

Comment: COM can be used from Python, yes. Whether and how the interactive generator can be accessed depends on the CANoe version you use. You have to check the CANoe documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **Interactive Generator** block CANNOT be accessed via COM using python or any other language. The reason being, the IG block is supposed to be *Interactive* and not to be *automated*.

Comment: Yes you are correct. Is it possible to simulate a CAN IG in a normal node? I am not familiar with CAPL coding. But the workaround I thought is to replicate the CAN IG in a node and then enable/disable the node. Is this possible?

Comment: It is possible. Both cyclic messages and one time messages can be configured in a CAPL node. The transmission can be configured in such a way that it can be controlled using system variables. Then, these system variables can be control using your python code via COM interface.